# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the sum of the following series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  n^{-n}$$

It definitely converges by ratio test.

Comment: [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

Comment: Do you have some reason to think there is a closed form?

Comment: Many special functions are considered as closed form of infinite series insofar they are referenced as standard functions : http://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales- (table 4a, page 33). This is not yet the case for the so called "Sophomores Dream" function, but that might happen...